# change svn used by svnant

Tags: linux, svn, build-process, svnant

I've installed a newer version of svn on my system in ~my/home/bin and put the path to it.
So now from command line a newer version of svn is used instead of the old one, located in /usr/bin/.

However svnant keeps using an older svn in /usr/bin.

How can I tell svnant to use a newer svn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen there svnant does not always uses the executable : http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnClientAdapter.html

1st-JavaHL native (JNI) subversion library (http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/bindings/javahl/)

2nd-JavaSVN (pure Java) subversion API implementation (http://tmate.org/svn/)

3rd-svn(.exe) command line client wrapper

For the first too you would have to upgrade the jar.

If it really uses the executable you should try putting your executable in the path first before the other svn exe or linking it to /usr/bin

```
ln -s /home/yourself/bin/svn /usr/bin/svn
```

Comment: How do I know which way is used by my svnant?

Comment: from there : http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/svn.html you can turn off the others using, javahl="false", in your antfile
Svnkit is default to false i don't know if you can see which one it uses

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do something like:

```
mv /usr/bin/svn /usr/bin/svn_old
ln -s ~/your/home/bin/svn /usr/bin/svn
```

So you have a copy of the old one if you need it, while linking the currently used binary to your new version.

Answer (score 0):

Add your new svn path to java.library.path